# jQuery .height() div with height:auto; unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery, height

I have a div (let's call it `#textbox_A`), which height in css is set to `height:auto`.

Via jQuery I want to get the height of the `#textbox_a` and give `#textbox_B` the same height:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#textbox_B").css("height", $("#textbox_A").height())  });
```

This works perfectly fine, if I use set values in the css for `#textbox_a` like `height:600px;`.

But as soon as I change it to `height:auto;` the `#textbox_B` is either bigger than `#textbox_a` (when `#textbox_a` has little content) or is smaller than `#textbox_a` (with `#textbox_a` having more content).

What could cause this behaviour?

**Edit:** I want to use the above function in [a slider](http://jsfiddle.net/jRcdw/7/), so that the right box, when it is not expanded, has the same height as the left one.

Comment: Can you explain your problem clearly? Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRcdw/) to explain.

Comment: I used the above function in this slider (http://jivstudio.com/demos/slider/), so the not expanded slider would always have the same height as the `#textbox_A`. I exchanged the `var sliderHeight` there with the above function, so that the height from `#textbox_A` would correlate to the height of `#textbox_B`.

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle of this? it is difficult to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I want to use the above function in a slider, so that the right box, when it is not expanded, has the same height as the left one. In the jsfiddle above it works just like I imagined it, but why does it behave differently when I use it in a more complex html document?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$("#textbox_B").css("height", $("#textbox_A").height()+ "px")
```

.height() does not return unit.

Answer (score 0):

is the #textbox_A relative to another div with a height itself? it might be the source of the problem. There can't be any height value if none is never set. 
So first thing you should define a div container with a height.

Comment: Yes, `#textbox_A` is set to `position:relative`. But even giving its parent div called `#content` a height value of 2000px etc. does not fix this problem.

Comment: What does it return when you display the height of A and B ? 0? undefined?

Comment: I linked a jsfiddle above, so that it becomes clear, what my intention is. When I use the function in my own html document it actually returns a valid value like "436". I have no clue why in my own html document the height of the right slider is sometimes less and sometimes more than the left box `#textbox_A`.

Comment: The slider height in my own document seems to behave percental to the left textbox `#textbox_A` and not like the slider in the jsfiddle does. If both boxes are at the same height and I add more content to the left textbox `#textbox_A` then the right slider is like 50px shorter. When I add even more content this difference grows even larger. Is this understandable?

Comment: @BlueHorizon, I have put my answer, I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jRcdw/11/

Changes made

1. `<div id="slider_wrapper">` changed to `<div id="slider_wrapper" style="overflow: auto;">`
2. On `doument.ready` function added

`$("#slider_wrapper").css("height", $("#textbox_A").css("height"));`

**Note**: If you want to show the scroll bar always, set `overflow: scroll`.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Alas this is not quite what I was looking for, but I don't need those two boxes to be the same size anymore. Thanks for all your answers here, guys and girls ;).